# Hard Water Filtration System

Tags: plumbing, water-filtration

My parent's house have a city/municipal corporation supply of water. Most of the times they face no issue with water but sometimes they  receive hard water or water with weird taste/smell.

I'm planning to install filter for hard water at the city water inlet point for my restrooms. I've attached the block diagram for the same. I'm installing different filter for different restrooms.

Block Diagram
[image]

I plan to use something like this 
https://amzn.eu/d/2rASVja or
https://amzn.eu/d/9NpWfNj

I plan to connect it near my city water inlet so I can get filtered water for any tap, shower, etc. I use in my restroom. This way I won't need a separate filter at my taps (2 nos. washbasin, 3-1 mixer tap), hand shower and overhead shower.

All piping are 1/2 inch.

I wish to get clarity on the following points

1. Will this scheme work?
2. Practical issues with this scheme.
3. What kind of pressure drop should I expect?
4. Any better alternatives?

Comment: The pressure drop depends on the fliw rate required, input pressure and type of filter. Look at the filter specs for it

Comment: We had an osmosis filter and used 4 inline with 4 sets in parallel to get the quality and flow rate.

Comment: Filtration, or water softener?

Comment: @keshlam, Filtration

Answer (score 3):

A shower filter is not appropriate for this design.  Look for a whole house product.

Also, a "filter" generally won't affect hard water.  For that, you need to look for a water softener system.

Comment: Reverse osmosis should reduce dissolved mineral content... but that isn't, technically, a filter